# Scan database columns into struct with slices

Tags: go

I have a struct with fields containing slices like so, and now I want to collect the columns from a sql-query into these slices

```
type StructOfSlices struct {
    Column1 []string
    Column2 []string
}
```

Is there an easier/more scalable/efficient way to do it than the below?

Here I first create a "single" version of the struct...

```
type StructSingle struct {
    Column1 string
    Column2 string
}

var s StructOfSlices

rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT column1, column2 FROM table")
```

...and then scan each individual single struct...

```
for rows.Next() {
    var single StructSingle

    db.Scan(&single.Column1, &single.Column2)

    s.Column1 = append(s.Column1, single.Column1)
    s.Column2 = append(s.Column2, single.Column2)
}
```

...and then append to the slice struct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's the way to do it. You're basically doing a pivot, there's no way I know of to do that automagically. Given that you've done it in just a couple of lines of code, I don't see a problem with your solution.

Since you're scanning into a variable per column, you don't actually need the `StructSingle` type at all - you could just use two local `string` variables, which would make it even simpler:

```
for rows.Next() {
    var col1, col2 string
    db.Scan(&col1, &col2)

    s.Column1 = append(s.Column1, col1)
    s.Column2 = append(s.Column2, col2)
}
```

And get rid of the `StructSingle` type entirely.

Comment: Another solution would be to have a custom type (`[]string`) implementing the `sql.Scanner` interface, where the `Scan` function would append the result. Probably overkill for this case.

Comment: That would work! It seems like more work/complexity though, plus it makes it less clear when reading the code what is actually happening. But if the real situation is more complicated than the example in the question, it might be warranted.